# C++ Reverse Linked List Recursively Why it works?

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list

This is the problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-linked-list/

I know the solution (and it's copy-pasted all around the internet), but I don't understand **how part of it works**...
So:

```
    struct ListNode{
        int data;
        ListNode* next;
    };

   ListNode* reverseList(ListNode* head) {
        if (!head || !(head -> next)) {
            return head;
        }
        ListNode* node = reverseList(head -> next);
        head -> next -> next = head;
        head -> next = NULL;
        return node;
    }
```

this works.

Now I am getting it trough the debugger and see things I don't understand...

Suppose we have a linked list:

```
1->2->3->NULL
```

1 ) We have passed the last `3->Null` part into `ListNode* node = reverseList(head->next);`
and it does `return head;` and now `ListNode* node = 3->NULL;`

[image]

Okay, `node == 3->NULL` and `head == 2->3->NULL`

2 ) Let's step over to `head->next->next = head`:

[image]

Now `head == 2->3->2->3...` **BUT WHY** `node  == 3->2->3->2...` **???**

*How are they connected? I am totally confused here.*

3) on next line `head -> next = NULL` we can see it again affects both `head` and `node` :

[image]

As you see, I don't understand the connection between `node` and `head`.
So I don't understand how it works and I feel I don't understand how those linked lists work in general.
Maybe someone can help me? Appreciate it.

Comment: "Now `head == 2->3->2->3..`. BUT WHY `node  == 3->2->3->2...` ???" The reversal function uses *chaining* to reverse the list. Note where the *recursive* call `ListNode* node = reverseList(head -> next);` is in the function. After it `returns` -- what happens? What two reassignments of pointers are made *after* every recursive call?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, hi! "ListNode* node = reverseList(head -> next);" returns ```node == 3->null``` as I understand (and you can see it in the screenshots of debugger). And it returns it to the state of the program where stack has ```node == 2->3->null```;

"What two reassignments of pointers are made after every recursive call?" do you mean these lines: 
```head -> next -> next = head; head -> next = NULL```
but they are made on ```head``` not on ```node```. So why does the ```node``` also affected? That is my question.

Comment: Recursive functions *"Unwind"* on return. Follow the path as the recursion *"Winds-In"* until `head == NULL | head->next == NULL`, then trace the returns as the recursion *"Unwinds"*. (that is how you have to look at recursion). On the first `return` control *"unwinds"* (returns to) the prior function call where the two assignments are made before that level of recursion *returns*... (which *"unwinds"* (returns to) the prior call). It's like starting at the center of an onion and working your way from the center-out, layer by later... Make a table with pencil and paper -- it helps `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, thanx for your support, but I think I knew it all before and that doesn't help with my question. Maybe you understand it at a deeper level but your explanation is not at my level of understanding or maybe you don't understand it. I don't know which is correct and prefer to think first (you are cleverer than me and just can't explain it to people with my IQ)...

Comment: I'm sorry. In your example, `1->2->3->NULL`, you recurse-in until `head->next` is `NULL`. You are on node where `head` is the node with `data == 2` at that time, your recursive call is with `head->next` (or where `data == 3`), the test `!(head -> next)` tests TRUE and you `return` a pointer to (start unwinding with) the node where `data == 3`. *Following the return* you are **back in** the call where `head` is the node with `data == 2`. Keep going.

Comment: Please note that while it works if the list is not too long, it is inefficient. The iterative solution is far preferable.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I do not have enough reputation to post a comment so I am going to post an answer and hope it helps you. I am going to use paint pictures to make things easier to visualize. Let's begin:

Let's say we have the list 1->2->3-> so it begins like so :

[image: examlpe]

Now we start the function and it runs until gets to the first recursion where it starts with a new head and we have the following situation:

[image: example]

Then the function runs again and we have the following outcome:

[image: example]

Then we start with a new head (3) but here the last function returns head because the `if` condition `head->next == NULL` is met. So we have:

[image: example]

Then we follow the function until the end changing the `head->next->next = head` and `head->next = NULL` so we have:

[image: example]

Then the function returns node and we return to the original call. Then we do the same steps and we end up with:

[image: example]

In the end the function returns node so we end up with:

[image: example]

Hope this helps you and sorry for the poor quality of the answer but I find it easier to solve recursion when visualizing it and the easiest way to visualize is to draw.

Comment: Hi, @Valgrim! Thank you for spending so much time on picture drawing) But I understand this before. The thing that confused me is that when we change ```head``` (```head->next-next = head``` and ```head->next = NULL```) it also affects the pointer ```node```. The thing is that ```node``` is a pointer and 'points' the the same address as ```head->next```.

Comment: What do you mean by affects. As you said it is a pointer that points to something. it is not affected if you change the value of that something as long as it points to the same thing. If you change `head->next` you don't affect the `node` pointer. You change the value of the pointer of `head` to be equal to something else. The `node` pointer remains unaffected.

Comment: you do affect it, look at the screenshots.

Comment: Hmm I run the code on C++ and it run just fine so I can't understand where you get the issue. Anyway I hope I helped you and hope you figure it out.

Comment: Thumbs up for creative lecturing!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, probably I have found an answer myself.
again, the problem is here:

```
        ListNode* node = reverseList(head -> next);
        head -> next -> next = head;
        head -> next = NULL;
        return node;
```

My question was why strings 2 and 3, which change `head`, also affect (change) `node`?

this is because `node` is a pointer and it 'points' to the same address in memory as `head->next`.

You actually can see this in the first screenshot:

[image]

0x100300020 is address of`node`

0x100300020 is address of `head->next`

they are pointing to the same address in memory.

So when we do:

```
        head -> next -> next = head;
        head -> next = NULL;
```

we also change it for the "thing stored" in the address where  `node` points to.